# How to update an array if this word is not in this array?

Tags: java, arrays

I am working on converting a Java file into an XREF file.

Here is my problem: **I want to check whether a word is in the database, if it's not in the database, add it to the database.**

Here is my code (it is a method):

```
void add(String word, int lineNumber) {
    /* If not a Java reserved word, insert word into the database,
       indicating that it is referenced on line lineNumber */

    // all Java reserved words; word at end guarantees
    String[] javaReservedWord = {
        "abstract", "assert", "boolean", "break",
            "byte", "case", "catch", "char", "class", "const", "continue",
            "default", "do", "double", "else", "enum", "extends", "false",
            "final", "finally", "float", "for", "goto", "if", "implements",
            "import", "instanceof", "int", "interface", "long", "native",
            "new", "null", "package", "private", "protected", "public",
            "return", "short", "static", "strictfp", "super", "switch",
            "synchronized", "this", "throw", "throws", "transient", "true",
            "try", "void", "volatile", "while", word
    };

    int i; // termination of for loop

    // traverse javaReservedWord and see if any entry matches word
    for (i = 0; !word.equals(javaReservedWord[i]); i++);

    // matches a reserved word, so don't add to database
    if (i < javaReservedWord.length - 1) return;

    /* doesn't match a reserved word, so proceed by searching to see if
          word is already in database */   
  }
```

In this method, Java file has been `StringTokenizer` into many words, which is `String word`, `lineNumber` is the line where this `word` is.

Comment: and what's your question?

Comment: `StringTokenizer` is a legacy class retained for compatibility reasons. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html Although it's not deprecated, it's use is discouraged.

Comment: You can't return word or lineNumber from a void method - nor can you return multiple values.

Comment: @m.aibin I have described in the question. Thank you!

Comment: @Thomas already modified, thank you!

Comment: @hege_hegedus yeah, I know. But my teacher lets us use this StringTokenizer. We should use HashMap nowadays.

Comment: And what if a word occures in multiple lines? Also what do you call a 'database'? Do you want to maintain that `javaReservedWord` array as a database?

Comment: whats your action if "a word is in the database"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't return anything from a method that you defined as void, nor can you return two things. You need a special class for that.

I would try something like that:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Word {

    private List<String> javaReservedWord = Arrays.asList(
            "abstract", "assert", "boolean", "break",
            "byte", "case", "catch", "char", "class", "const", "continue",
            "default", "do", "double", "else", "enum", "extends", "false",
            "final", "finally", "float", "for", "goto", "if", "implements",
            "import", "instanceof", "int", "interface", "long", "native",
            "new", "null", "package", "private", "protected", "public",
            "return", "short", "static", "strictfp", "super", "switch",
            "synchronized", "this", "throw", "throws", "transient", "true",
            "try", "void", "volatile", "while"
    );

    class WordAndNumber {
        private String word;
        private int lineNumber;

        public WordAndNumber(String word, int lineNumber) {
            this.word = word;
            this.lineNumber = lineNumber;
        }

        public String getWord() {
            return word;
        }

        public int getLineNumber() {
            return lineNumber;
        }
    }

    private WordAndNumber add(String word, int lineNumber) {

        if (javaReservedWord.contains(word)) {
            return null;
        } else {
            // add in DB

            return new WordAndNumber(word, lineNumber);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you assuming each line is 1 word long? Also, why are you passing a lineNumber as a parameter for `add()`? Would the user know which lineNumber to enter for the method?

As for your `add()` method, why do you have this array inside of the method instead of a private array outside in the declaration of the class? What if you plan to access this array from another method? By doing this you save the amount of code that you're methods will have. To add a word to an array of Strings you can do something like this:

```
String[] javaReservedWord = {
    "abstract", "assert", "boolean", "break",
    "byte", "case", "catch", "char", "class", "const", "continue",
    "default", "do", "double", "else", "enum", "extends", "false",
    "final", "finally", "float", "for", "goto", "if", "implements",
    "import", "instanceof", "int", "interface", "long", "native",
    "new", "null", "package", "private", "protected", "public",
    "return", "short", "static", "strictfp", "super", "switch",
    "synchronized", "this", "throw", "throws", "transient", "true",
    "try", "void", "volatile", "while"
};

String[] temp = new String[javaReservedWord.length + 1];
for(int i = 0; i < javaReservedWord.length; i++)
    temp[i] = javaReservedWord[i];

temp[javaReservedWord.length + 1] = word;
 javaReservedWord = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Init a HashSet as the class field (will be set up by classloader) - you won't lose time to init the field each time you want to add a line.

HashSet will provide a constant search time (instead of lineat for ArrayList or Array) - search will be performed faster.

```
public class Main {
Set<String> blackList = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("abstract", "assert", "boolean", "break",
        "byte", "case", "catch", "char", "class", "const", "continue",
        "default", "do", "double", "else", "enum", "extends", "false",
        "final", "finally", "float", "for", "goto", "if", "implements",
        "import", "instanceof", "int", "interface", "long", "native",
        "new", "null", "package", "private", "protected", "public",
        "return", "short", "static", "strictfp", "super", "switch",
        "synchronized", "this", "throw", "throws", "transient", "true",
        "try", "void", "volatile", "while"));

void addAllowed(String word, int lineNumber) {
    if (!blackList.contains(word)){
        add(word, lineNumber);
    }
}

void add(String word, int lineNumber){
    //ToDo: code to add word to database
}
```

}